# Facebook SDK 7.2 Unity Login Crash on device iOS, not in editor

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine

Everything is working perfectly inside unity editor, but when I build for iOS and test on device I get this error everytime I try to login to facebook:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'can't start iterating in the middle of an iteration'

[Xcode Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pklHb.png)

This is my code inside Unity:

```
public Button fbLoginBtn;

public void FbLogin()
{
    var perms = new List<string>(){"public_profile", "email", "user_friends"};
    FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(perms, AuthCallback);
}

private void AuthCallback (ILoginResult result) 
{
    if (FB.IsLoggedIn) 
    {
        // AccessToken class will have session details
        var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
        // Print current access token's User ID
        Debug.Log(aToken.UserId);
        // Print current access token's granted permissions
        foreach (string perm in aToken.Permissions) 
        {
            Debug.Log(perm);
        }
    } else {
        Debug.Log("User cancelled login");
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: As far as I can see there's nothing wrong with your code. I would try using the sample Scenes that come with the Facebook SDK to rule out it is something on their side. If it turns out it is, I would download Unity SDK 7.2.2 and if it still reproduces, file a bug under developers.facebook.com/bugs